# XCode Build and Run

Tags: xcode

I recently reinstalled OSX, and am having a slight annoyance with XCode. Before I reinstalled, I could just hit CMD + Enter, and it would build, then flip the main editor screen to the debugger, where it would show NSLogs, crashes, etc. Now, when I hit CMD + Enter, it just runs the app and stays in the code editor screen. Is there an option I'm missing? I've scoured the preferences, and can't seem to find anything.

Comment: What version of Xcode (3 or 4) are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences > Debugging and check the "On Start" drop down.

Comment: Great, but it is opening them in a new window, how do I command them to group in the main window?

Comment: Preferences > General > Layout

Comment: I was just getting ready to say, that I closed my active project, and under there was all-in-one layout! Thank you so much!